Principled volume does not work in eevee
I used a principled volume on a cube for testing and the cube just turns invisible. I’ve switched to cycles and it does show the volume. So I played with the volumetric settings and it shows a tiny bit for a split second, like a triangle and it disappeared. Is there any way to fix this?

You need to go into the Render panel, increase the Sampling and under Volumetrics decrease the Tile Size and increase the Samples:


It sadly didn’t work. But I can tell it’s trying to work because how slow blender is being

Please show a screenshot of your blender interface or even share your file?
